# making Ramda.js functions globally accessible (without R. )

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, ramda.js

I want to use Ramda.js functions without typing `R.`

I've tried to add all the functions to the global scope but it doesn't work this is my try

```
const R = require('ramda'); // R is an object containing lots of functions
for(let x in R) {
    global.x = x;
}
```

also, I want to know how to do it using Ramda library itself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any specific reason for this.

Comment: @HarshGupta it is a fuss when you always need to type R.someMethod while working with Ramda, if you try the library you will know what I'm trying to say

Comment: Ramda once had this ability on its own.  We removed it as it didn't really fit well with the Ramda philosophy.  And for this same reason, you really can't do this entirely with Ramda functions.  Ramda does not modify user or global objects.  You have to do this yourself.

Comment: Note there is a small overlap between the `window` API names and Ramda's ones: you'll have to find a way to skip those or to accept that they'll be shadowed.  At the moment, I think it's just `find` and `toString`, but who knows when that might change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the property called x, rather than the x property:
Also, be sure to assign the value of `R[x]` back, rather than the property name `x`

```
global[x] = R[x];
```

You could also try iterating through getOwnPropertyNames:

```
for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(R)) {
    global[prop] = R[prop]
}
```

Or, if applicable, just destructure the properties you need into your scope:

```
const {someProp, someOtherProp} = R;
```

Comment: @EngineerPassion That doesn't give me much to go on. Why is the loop not working for you? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening? What is the error, if there is one?

Comment: destructure works fine but the for loop doesn't make the method globally accessible

Comment: @EngineerPassion Sorry, I've just fixed the post.

Comment: I personally have switched to the destructuring technique for small samples, and let something like Webpack handle it in more complex situations.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, while I disagree that typing additional 2 characters could be termed as a fuss, but it is how you feel.

Like @uber5001 mentioned the de-structure technique, it is one way, but it means you first need to `require` entire ramda functions into `R` then retrieve the functions you need.

You can also `require` only the required functions:

```
const uniq = require('ramda/src/uniq')
const zip = require('ramda/src/zip')
// and so on
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Setting all the functions of Ramda as globals might be risky. Ramda has a lot of functions, and some of them might override existing globals you have. A better practice (which is still considered a bad practice because you can still shadow-name variables) is the `with` statement, which destructures all the properties of the object while not overriding your outer scope variables.

```
with(R) {
  pipe(
    map(x => x ** 2),
    filter(x => x > 24)
  )([3, 4, 5, 6]); // => [25, 36]
}
```

Note that the with statement is disabled in strict mode.